# Having String returned from String.split include partial of matching elements

Tags: java

```
final String json = "\"name\" : \"john\" , \"worth\" : \"123,456\"";    
String[] ss = json.split("\"\\s*,\\s*\"");
System.out.println(json);
for (String s : ss) {
    System.out.println("--> " + s);
}
```

The output is

```
"name" : "john" , "worth" : "123,456"
--> "name" : "john
--> worth" : "123,456"
```

Is there any way I can get

```
"name" : "john" , "worth" : "123,456"
--> "name" : "john"
--> "worth" : "123,456"
```

Comment: Other than two missing quotation marks in the current output, there is no difference between current output and desired output. Was that what you were referring to? A simple bit of description of your problem goes a lot further than code alone...

Comment: Your "side-effect" is very predictable, so the easiest way is probably to just parse string like you do now and "fix" it afterwards. Or you can use dedicated json parser, for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Regex

While I must agree that using a JSON parser makes a lot more sense, even if you want to use regex, String.split() is not the right tool. Use a [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and a [Matcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

```
final String json = "\"name\" : \"john\" , \"worth\" : \"123,456\"";
final Pattern pattern =
    Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"\\s*:\\s*\"(.*?)\"", Pattern.DOTALL);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + ":" + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
name:john
worth:123,456
```

And if you really want to retrieve the quotes, change the pattern to

```
final Pattern pattern =
    Pattern.compile("(\".*?\")\\s*:\\s*(\".*?\")", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Output:

```
"name":"john"
"worth":"123,456"
```

Of course this won't help with different JSON structures like nested object structures, arrays, primitives etc.

---

### Using JSON parsers

But if your question is just about how to do this with JSON parsers, here is an example using [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html):

```
final String json = "{\"name\" : \"john\" , \"worth\" : \"123,456\"}";
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final Iterator<String> it = jsonObject.keys();
while(it.hasNext()){
    final String nextKey = it.next();
    System.out.println(nextKey + ":" + jsonObject.getString(nextKey));
}
```

No classes needed. Output:

```
name:john
worth:123,456
```

Comment: Thanks. JSONObject does meet my requirement. gjson doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit like parsing XML yourself. You *can* do it, but why bother? There are plenty of [JSON parsers](http://www.json.org/java/) available. Use one of them to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Because most JSON parsers required my to defined a class. However, the string respond I am getting is being dynamically changed frequently. The number of properties from the respond string is not always being fixed. I just do not want to release a new software just because the number of properties is different

Comment: @Yan: While some parsers may require you to have an existing class to serialize to/from, I'm sure not all do - see seanizer's answer, for example. You don't need more than *one* parser which does what you want, do you?